# Stacked bar symbols for points in ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, 3d, subsurface

Is there a way to represent single points as stacked bars using multiple elevation attributes on the points in AGOL 3d Scene or by building in ArcGIS Pro and pushing out to AGOL?

I would want to color code each section (between a minimum of four elevations on each point - meaning at least 3 sections) so that the Z axis would be a column/stack like in a 3d bar chart.

Comment: I think that you should keep this question focused on ArcGIS Online only.  If you need to also ask about the ArcGIS Pro functionality then that can be done in a separate question.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by 'multiple elevation attributes'. Are you trying to use a stacked-bar chart as an icon?